# Как парсить другую страницу в авито?

Tags: requests, bs4

```
import json
import time
import bs4
import requests as rq
from bs4 import *

global page, url

for page in range(10):
    url = f'https://www.avito.ru/voronezh?p={page}&q=%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA'

response = rq.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

postNews = soup.find('div', class_='index-content-_KxNP')

with open('notebook.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(postNews))
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто поменяйте часть с запросом в ссылке.

Вам необходимо закодировать строку с поисковым запросом в URL-формат, вы можете сделать это с помощью функции `urllib.urlencode()`:

```
import json
import time
import bs4
import requests as rq
from bs4 import *
import urllib

global page, url

req = 'Ноутбук'
for page in range(10):
    url = f'https://www.avito.ru/voronezh?p={page}&q={urllib.urlencode(req)}'

response = rq.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

postNews = soup.find('div', class_='index-content-_KxNP')

with open('notebook.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(postNews))
```